# Automate source maps upload React Native

Tags: react-native, source-maps, sentry, react-native-sentry

How can i automate source maps uploading process for Sentry in React Native?

```
react-native bundle \
  --dev false \
  --platform android \
  --entry-file index.js \
  --bundle-output android.main.bundle \
  --sourcemap-output android.main.bundle.map
```

I use this to upload it manually.I think it can be done by webpack.Is it possible or any solutions??